# Schema generation from hsql

Tags: database, schema, hsqldb

Is it possible to generate a database schema from hsql?

Regards,
Kurt

Answer (score 1):

[HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org) supports the `SCRIPT` statement (just one word) which returns a result set containing the schema definition and the database settings.

The result set does not contain the data in the tables.

Comment: Does this return the contents of the <database name>.script file that is found in the folder with the database?

Comment: Only the definitions are returned, not the table data.